# NodeJs Readable Error When Reading From Stream

Tags: node.js, node-streams

I want to print the output every 1 second but i get the below error. I thought that read method is called synchronously but it seems that is not the case. Can someone explain how the read method executes and why i get this error?

```
const {Readable} = require('stream');

var out = new Readable({

    read(size){
        console.log('read');

        setTimeout(()=>{


        console.log(this.k);

        console.log('before push');

        this.push(String.fromCharCode(this.k++)+'\n');

        console.log('after push\n');
        if(this.k>65){
            this.push(null);
            console.log('null\n');
        }

    },1000);


    }

});
out.k = 65;
out.pipe(process.stdout);
```

**And i get this error:**

```
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
    Error: stream.push() after EOF
        at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:240:30)
        at Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
        at Timeout.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (C:\Users\x90540\Node\index.js:106:14)
        at ontimeout (timers.js:475:11)
        at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:310:5)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:270:5)
```

Comment: It works for me, can't reproduce the error. BTW setTimeout makes the execution asynchronous.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it too. Not able to reproduce.

Comment: @AakashMalhotra Iam using Node version 8.9.4

Comment: @Dolby Oh alright, let me check on that version. I am on the latest LTS.

Comment: @AakashMalhotra  http://tpcg.io/hZPSNr Check here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who comes to read this later on:

This behavior would not reproduce if you use the updated version of Node. A detailed discussion of this can be found here:

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3203#issuecomment-355137794

Answer (score 2):

When you are pushing `null` you are closing the stream, but you are not clearing the timeout, so then you are trying to write on a closed stream. Try it like this:

```
const { Readable } = require('stream');

var prevTimeout;
var out = new Readable({

    read(size) {

        prevTimeout = setTimeout(()=> {

            console.log(this.k);

            this.push(String.fromCharCode(this.k++)+'\n');

            if (this.k > 67) {

                this.push(null);

                clearTimeout(prevTimeout);
            }
        },
        500);
    }
});

out.k = 65;

out.pipe(process.stdout);
```

More info about streams: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_streams

Comment: If the condition is met, that means that we are want to finish our stream and no others callbacks (setTimeout) will be executed. How am i trying to write on the stream when there are no other callbacks?

Comment: setTimeout is added to the end of the event loop

Comment: So you want to make sure that when you close your stream you also stop the execution of your timeout. That's exactly what clearTimeout does.

Comment: @AakashMalhotra What do you mean?

Comment: @Dolby Because with setTimeout you add a task to be executed later. Since you close the stream, you want to cancel the task. Try the same without setTimeout to see how read behaves.

Comment: @AlexG But the stream is closed inside from  that task. Who creates another task?

Comment: - the read function is called multiple times by nodeJS. You can read more here https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_streams
- Try to run the same code but without timeout as Alex suggested. You would see read is called multiple times.
- It's possible that in execution of current call of read function the settimeout added by previous call to read hasn't been executed yet. For more on this you should read more about how event loop works in JS

Comment: @AakashMalhotra the read function is called when push is called

Comment: @Dolby In addition, try adding logs before, after and inside the setTimeout callback to see more clearly the order of execution. The moment you are pushing something, you cause read to run again registering another callback, the last time at a closed stream.

Comment: @AlexG I have logs inserted as you can see in the post. The execution flow with or without the settimeout is different each time. If each time you call push the read function executes, then why this error does not occur without settimeout?

Comment: @Dolby Because without setTimeout you are not adding anything to be executed later.

Comment: @AlexG and Dolby One difference that I see is:
In the online editor, the Dolby provided the read function is called even when you push null.
BUT on my local system with (node 10.x) the pushing null does not call read again.

Comment: I don't see any changes in the doc history though

Comment: @AlexG When NOT using settimeout, the read function is executed only once, even though we pushed something in the data ("The moment you are pushing something, you cause read to run again") according to you. But when using settimeout the read function is called twice.

Comment: @AakashMalhotra When NOT using settimeout, the read function is executed only once, even though we pushed something in the data . But when using settimeout the read function is called twice.

Comment: @Dolby I think i found it :) read this: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3203#issuecomment-355137794

Comment: @Dolby Hence the reason, I am not facing the same issue in the node version I am using. SO updating the node version is one solution.

Comment: @AakashMalhotra Okay so there is a bug. The simplest explanation. Thank you. (Almost convinced me that iam noob in node)

Comment: @Dolby It happens with all of us :) BTW I have added it as an answer for others who may land here later. It might be easier for them not to go through comments. So if you feel it helped you can mark it as an answer. Thanks.